# How to get LastOutgoingCall from CallLog.Calls android?

Tags: android

I have problem, I don't know how to get `LastOutgoingCall` from `android.provider.CallLog.Calls`. There is a public method `getLastOutgoingCall` but I don't know how to accces it. 
I can create object `CallLog.Calls` but there is no such method like `getLastOutgoingCall`.

I know there is "Query the call log database for the last dialed number" but have no idea how to get and use it. For any tips and answers, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String lastDialed = CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(getApplicationContext());
```

and of course add the permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use content provider to get list of outgoing calls and arrange them in DESC order according to time and retrieve the first value of cursor.

Do some research to work on Content Provider.

Comment: That I know but are there some way to use getLastOutgoingCall method from CallLog.Calls?

Comment: No there is no such method in my knowledge.